# How to pass DataTable as a parameter to Stored Procedure by not commiting the current session transaction?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, fluent-nhibernate, table-valued-parameters

My code looks like this:

```
public void InsertSampleData(DataTable tempTable)
    {
       session.Transaction.Commit();
        var connection = session.GetSessionImplementation().Connection;
        using (var sqlConnection = (SqlConnection)connection)
        {
            using (var cmd = sqlConnection.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.CommandText = "dbo.insertData";
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@sItems", SqlDbType.Structured);
                var sqlParam = cmd.Parameters["@Items"];
                sqlParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                sqlParam.TypeName = "[dbo].[DataItemType]";
                sqlParam.Value = tempTable;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
```

The code works fine but if I do not commit the transaction it throws an exception as shown

> System.InvalidOperationException: ExecuteNonQuery requires the command to have a transaction when the connection assigned to the
>   command is in a pending local transaction.  The Transaction property
>   of the command has not been initialized.

But I don't want the transaction to be commited yet before completing the whole operation. How can I achieve this??

Comment: what does GetSessionImplementation  return?

Comment: @Baz1nga its returns something that implements [ISession](http://mausch.github.com/nhibernate-3.2.0GA/html/fcb2b8a0-0c03-8056-91a1-3b26691eaffe.htm) its an nhibernate thing

Comment: NHibernate.Engine.ISessionImplementor GetSessionImplementation()
    Member of NHibernate.ISession

Summary:
Gets the session implementation.

Returns:
An NHibernate implementation of the NHibernate.Engine.ISessionImplementor interface

Remarks:
This method is provided in order to get the NHibernate implementation of the session from wrapper implementions.  Implementors of the NHibernate.ISession interface should return the NHibernate implementation of this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue is that the transaction was supposed to use has been committed and already has been disposed, thus either instantiate a new SqlConnection or get a new session and then run the query as part of the new session.

```
public void InsertSampleData(DataTable tempTable)
{
    session.Transaction.Commit();

    using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(session.GetSessionImplementation()
                                       .Connection.ConnectionString))
    {
        using (var cmd = sqlConnection.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "dbo.insertData";
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@sItems", SqlDbType.Structured);
            var sqlParam = cmd.Parameters["@Items"];
            sqlParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            sqlParam.TypeName = "[dbo].[DataItemType]";
            sqlParam.Value = tempTable;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

or

```
public void InsertSampleData(DataTable tempTable)
    {
       session.Transaction.Commit();
        var connection = session.SessionFactory.OpenSession().GetSessionImplementation().Connection;
        using (var sqlConnection = (SqlConnection)connection)
        {
            using (var cmd = sqlConnection.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.CommandText = "dbo.insertData";
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@sItems", SqlDbType.Structured);
                var sqlParam = cmd.Parameters["@Items"];
                sqlParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                sqlParam.TypeName = "[dbo].[DataItemType]";
                sqlParam.Value = tempTable;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
```

BTW, why are using SQLConnection why arent you exexurting the query using the Nhibernate Session, you could do the everything that you are doing right now using the Nhibernate Session.

```
session.CreateSQLQuery(<your sql>)
.SetParameters()   //and various other API to set your parameters
.ExecuteUpdate();
```

Comment: Yes I have tried using Nhibernate session but how do you pass a DataTable as parameter because the stored procedure expects a table valued parameter